# Draw lines between methods in code editor of IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, methods, comments, code-editor

Is there a way to make IntelliJ distinguish where each method’s body starts and stops? Perhaps drawing a line to separate the methods visually?

Seems kind of silly nowadays to be typing a “flower box” of asterisks as comments around method headings. The IDE should know where each method begins and ends.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## “Method separators”

Yes. IntelliJ calls the feature “method separators”.

In `Preferences` > `Editor` > `General` > `Appearance`, check the `Show method separators` box.

[image: screen shot of Preferences dialog box showing 'Show method separators' checkbox]

You can even control the color of the line drawn between methods. See `Preferences` > `Editor` > `Color Scheme` > `General` > `Code` > `Method separator color` > `Foreground` field where you can type in a the [hex triplet code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors) for a color in RGB. The default in the [*Darcula* theme](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/user-interface-themes.html) is `4D4D4D`.

[image: screen shot of Preferences showing 'Method separator color' editor]

The code editor then displays a line across the pane, directly above the name of the method. For example, in this screenshot see the line above the method named `MainView`.

[image: screen shot of IntelliJ method editor displaying a thin line above a method name]

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work for JavaScript. Any clues?

Comment: Why is only the foreground colour adjustable? I'd like to change the separator's style. For example, for using equal signs instead of a thin line of underscores...