# Insulation of intellij IDEA Java methods by lines

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, intellij-plugin

I'm using java with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2, Is there a way to separate the Methods with lines in the class, (like the image below)
because I always wanted to separate the Methods with lines other than the lines of comments for more clarity of vision.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013181/draw-lines-between-methods-in-code-editor-of-intellij